# Active sidebar pill is no longer active

Tags: angular

I'm creating a sidebar for my angular application, so far it's working good.

The problem is that I want the active pill to stay `active` while I'm still on that interface but it fades as soon as I click anywhere else than the sidebar.

NB: the sidebar is an independant component

sidebar.component.html :

```
    <nav class="sidebar col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">

    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column sidebar-nav" >

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li "nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="excelDash">Excel</a>
        </li>
        <li  class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="manager-dashboard">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    <a (click)="logout()" class="logout-button"><em class="fa fa-power-off"></em> LogOut</a>
 </nav>
```

sidebar.component.css

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Scrollable contents if viewport is shorter than content. */
  background: #cf022b; }

.nav-pills .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-pills .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #e80230;
  font-family: "OpenSans",sans-serif; }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `routerLinkActive` to set active item by changing the rout:

```
<nav class="sidebar col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column sidebar-nav" >
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="home" routerLinkActive='active'>Home</a>
        </li>
        <li "nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="excelDash" routerLinkActive='active'>Excel</a>
        </li>
        <li  class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="manager-dashboard" routerLinkActive='active'>Dashboard</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    <a (click)="logout()" class="logout-button"><em class="fa fa-power-off"></em> LogOut</a>
 </nav>
```

in css:

```
.active {
     background-color: #e80230;
     font-family: "OpenSans",sans-serif;
}
```

working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlinkactive-n3wxre).